# Failed to install windows patch

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have an issue during installing Windows Patch for Windows 10.

I have tried:

1. Clean Disk Cleanup.
2. Scanned AV
3. Restart wuauserv
4. Delete file in Windows Update folder

Comment: C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\cbs.log help?

Comment: Please post online your `C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\cbs.log`. What issue exactly?

Comment: Windows Update log is more helpful than CBS.log, without more information, this question cannot be answered

Answer (score 0):

did you try this [computerworld][1]

You don't have to take patches the way they're dealt.
Step 1: Wait.
Step 2: Back up.
Step 3: Make sure the updates you don't want are hidden –...
Step 4: Clear out your Advanced Options.
Step 5: Open up your internet connection.
Step 6: Run Windows Update.
Step 7: Lock down your Advanced Options
[1]: https://www.computerworld.com/article/3215668/8-steps-to-install-windows-10-patches-like-a-pro.html